# How to stop null from printing

Tags: java, null, java-print

When executing my program it keeps displaying "null" on line 13 I want to know what's wrong on my algorithm for it keeps printing null.

```
private class SpadeIterator implements Iterator<Card>{
    private int nextCardSpade;
    private List<Card> cards;
    private int count=0;
    private SpadeIterator(List cards) {
        this.cards=cards;
        this.nextCardSpade = cards.size()-1;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasNext() {
        count++;
        if(nextCardSpade<0)
            return false;
        //nextCardSpade--;
        return true;
    }

   @Override
    public Card next() {

        int i=0;
        this.count=i;
        Card temp = cards.get(nextCardSpade);

        while(hasNext()){    //find SPADES
            temp=cards.get(nextCardSpade--);
            i++;

            if(temp.suit.value == Suit.SPADES.value)
                return temp;
        }
        //DONT MOVE
        return null;
        //nextCardSpade--;      //DONT DELETE

    }
}
```

[Current Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e4urt.png)

The results are meant to show the 13 spades without returning null at the end.

Comment: Then just check for the null

Comment: Your `next()` method shouldn't contain any case which returns `null`. If there is no proper element to be returned then it is `hasNext()` method job to return `false`.

Comment: Also your `hasNext` method should not modify the state (increasing count) of the object in any way.

Comment: Yeah but i need to return something otherwise  the program doesn't run

Comment: If there is no next then ```next``` is supposed to throw an NoSuchElementException, not return a value.  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html#next().  And most callers will refrain from calling ```next``` unless ```hasNext``` says there is a next element.

Answer (score 0):

Check that `nextCardSpade` equals to 0 also:

```
if (nextCardSpade <= 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `next()` method shouldn't contain any case which would return invalid value like `null`. If there is no next element to be returned it is `hasNext()` method's **job** to return `false` to prevent you from calling `next()`.

So your code should look more like

```
class SpadeIterator implements Iterator<Card>{
    private int spadesCounter = 0;
    private Iterator<Card> cardsIt;

    private SpadeIterator(List<Card> cards) {
        cardsIt = cards.iterator();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasNext() {
        return spadesCounter<13; // we can't put spacesCounter++ here because 
                                 // we should be able to call `hasNext()` many times
                                 // and still get same answer,
                                 // so `hasNext()` shouldn't change any state 
                                 // (at least one which could cause changing its result)
    }

    @Override
    public Card next() {
        Card temp = cardsIt.next(); //if our `hasNext()` returned `false` but we 
                                    //didn't check or ignored it, this will CORRECTLY 
                                    //throw NoSuchElementException 
        while(temp.suit.value != Suit.SPADES.value){
            temp = cardsIt.next();
        }
        spadesCounter++;
        return temp;
    }
}
```

OR if you simply want to iterate over list and print only selected elements you can use streams with filtering like

```
List<Card> cards = ...//not really important how get it
cards.stream()
     .filter(card -> card.suit.value == Suit.SPADES.value)
     .forEach(card -> System.out.println(card));
```

or even simpler

```
for (Card card : cards){
    if(card.suit.value == Suit.SPADES.value){
        System.out.println(card);
    }
}
```

Comment: There's a requirement to throw NoSuchElementException when there is no next element to return from ```next()```.  In your code this is implicit in the call to ```cardsIt.next()```.  You likely know this, I'm just pointing it out for the original poster.

Comment: @another-dave Thanks for pointing that out. I updated my answer a little to include this info.